# how to compare two strings from different arrays, if one string contains another?

Tags: powershell

I want to compare if one string (f.e. Edi) contains in another string (f.e. Edil). I wrote a script with out-string, because later I need to compare two obejcts (all users from AD with accounts from NTFSsecurity (permission for folders)).

```
$AlleBenutzer = ("Adam","Edi", "Georg","Kate")
$Benutzer = ("Adaml", "Edil", "Eval")
foreach ($u in $AlleBenutzer) {$L = $u | Out-String ; write-host $L}
foreach ($v in $Benutzer) {$M = $v | Out-String; write-host $M}

foreach ($user in $L) {if ($M -match $user ) {Write-Host $M}}
```

I become output from line 3 and 4, but no output from line 6. I don't see my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Out-String` here - your array values are already strings. You can run the list of substrings (user names) through a nested set of `Where-Object` pipelines to test them all:

```
$AlleBenutzer = ("Adam","Edi", "Georg","Kate")
$Benutzer = ("Adaml", "Edil", "Eval")

$AlleBenutzer |Where-Object {
  $user = $_
  # If any value in $Benutzer matches the user name, 
  # this expression will evaluate to _something_, 
  # iow. $true in the outer Where-Object 
  $Benutzer |Where-Object {$_ -like "*$user*"}
}
```